# Want to simply pass a variable to Php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to pass a variable to Php function

```
FromDateChange()
{
   var FromDateSelected = document.getElementById('FromDate').value;
}
```

I don't want to reload the page, so know hidden forms do I have to use ajax can't find a simple way of passing one variable.

Comment: What is it ? Php, Javascript, Pseudo language ? What do you have tried ? You doesn't explain anything...

Comment: Hi, I have tried writing javascript inside PHP the code above is javascript.

Comment: To get a useful answer, don't ask about your attempted solution but the original problem. What are you trying to do? What is the variable's purpose on PHP's end?

Comment: onchange event the variable is sent to php php then converts it for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't write JavaScript into a PHP function, if you want to pass variable from js to php, you need to make an ajax call !

Comment: Yeah I know i have tried looking but struggling to pass a simple variable from javascript to PHP using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var date = $("#FromDate").val()
// Send via ajax
$.ajax({
          url: 'phpCode.php',  // separate page to do your php processing/insert or current page
          type: 'POST',
          data: {date:date},

   success: function(response){
          alert(response);   // Will display "Successfully submitted form";
         // response from php side, in echo in the code or return. Or a message you choose to put it

      }
    });
});
```

PHP page for example

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
// Do database stuff
// on successful insert for example
if($affected_rows > 0 ){
echo "Successfully submitted form";   // This is your "response" on JQuery side
}
```

Comment: is says $ is not defined

Comment: `$` is the jquery object. The javascript above uses `JQuery` therefore you have to include JQuery js in your page

Comment: You need to import the JQuery library and scripts from the JQuery CDN or download them and include them in your pages, I saw you listed Ajax so I assumed you knew that

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax. Here's an example:

First you have to implement your frontend with javascript. So there, the javascript variable will passing through ajax to the php script.

```
<script>
    var my_string = "Hello World";
    $.ajax({
        url: "receiver.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {key_mystring: my_string}
    });
</script>
```

So and in your *receiver.php* you get the variable through the $_POST variable.

```
<?php
    $my_string = $_POST["key_mystring"];
?>
```